# How to create multiple .env in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, web-config, vue-component, vue-cli

I am stuck in vue.js,  how to manage multiple env for multiple servers like local, development and production ?

Comment: Have you read this? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create different .env file for different environment like 
`.env.development`, `.env.staging`, and `.env.production` and in your package.json create build script like this -

```
"scripts": {
"build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --modern",
"build-stage": "vue-cli-service build --mode staging --modern",
"build-prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode production --modern",
}
```

For details please follow this doc https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html